# How can I use find and replace to move text into a frame in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have a book's worth of text. In it, there are sections of text that are marked by starting with `{s}` and ending with `{/s}`. It's sort of like custom markdown, and it looks like this:
[image: preformatted]

What I want to do is take the text in between the two markers, and move it into a frame that floats to the right, so that it looks like this:

[image: postformatted]

Note that the markers themselves, the `{s}` and `{/s}` are removed in the process.

Is there a way I can use the Search & Replace function to do this? Or some similar batch process? There are many hundreds of instances of this, so it would be tedious to do this manually.

Comment: It looks like this will require a macro.  If you want to try writing a macro and get stuck, post your code on stackoverflow or the OpenOffice forum, and someone can probably help.

Comment: @JimK, thanks for responding. I tried recording a Macro, but I think this approach might be too complicated for me. If scripting my own Macro is the only option, then I'm afraid that might effectively mean it is not available to me.